# "I care about you" in French

Tags: traduction, anglais

How would you say "I care about you" in French, by which you mean to whom it is directed at that their well-being and happiness are of concern to you?

Specifically, I want to capture these types of situations:
- showing concern for a friend who has fallen into difficult circumstances
- a parent explaining to a child who feels alone and fears abandonment that everything's okay
- explaining to a lover that your gestures of affection come from a sincere place

I presume for the last, « je tiens à toi » is spot on. My French is poor so I am unable to appreciate the strength of the sentiment.

Answer (score 6):

Je ne vois pas d'autres traductions que *Je tiens à toi*.

Mais à l'usage, c'est intime, c'est presque aussi fort qu'un *je t'aime*. Donc une relation d'amitié forte ou d'amour.

Pour atténuer cet effet, je pense qu'on peut utiliser *je tiens à notre amitié*.

Comment: « Je tiens à notre amitié » ne veut pas vraiment dire la même chose.

Answer (score 4):

For these given situations, I would say:

- "showing concern for a friend who has fallen into difficult circumstances": *je suis (de tout cœur) avec toi, je te soutiens, tu peux compter sur moi*
- "a parent explaining to a child who feels alone and fears abandonment that everything's okay": *je suis là (pour toi), je tiens à toi*
- "explaining to a lover that your gestures of affection come from a sincere place": *je tiens à toi*

Comment: I feel "*tu peux compter sur moi*" as being slightly different, it introduces an idea of reliance, more than just concern, and I think it would better translate as "You can rely on  me".

Comment: Yes, you're right. Still, I think I could say it in this particular context, but you are right to note the slightly different meaning, thanks!

Comment: "Je suis là" is spot on for the second case.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "*je tiens à toi*", which would suit every case and that you can modulate with adverbs to suit the situation : "*je tiens beaucoup à toi*", "*je tiens vraiment à toi*", "*je tiens très fort (vraiment très fort) à toi*" ; you could use :

to a friend: "*tu comptes beaucoup pour moi*" ; "*tu es un ami très cher*",
to a child: "*tu m'es très cher*",
to a lover: the previous ones plus "*je t'aime*".
*Aimer* is one of the received translations for the verb "care" outside a nursing
context. And the usual one when in a negative situation : "I don't much care for him/her" -> *"je ne l'aime pas beaucoup"*.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context (in particular, the register and the occasion on which you are going to say/write it), other possibilities describing very similar feelings (if not exactly the same) are:

> Je te souhaite tout le bonheur du monde
>
> Je te souhaite tout plein de bonheur
>
> Je tiens (très fort) à toi
>
> Prends soin de toi
>
> Ton bonheur m'importe beaucoup

Comment: Je suis d'accord que ce sont des tournures que l'on emploierait naturellement en français avec la même intention, mais il faut bien indiquer que la signification n'est pas exactement la même.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Absolument, réponse éditée. Mais un peu plus de contexte aiderait certainement à donner une réponse plus précise.

Answer (score 0):

Parmi les propositions de *[Linguee](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/i-care-about-you-en-francais)* lorsqu'il est lié à 'you':

> Je me soucie de toi.
>
> Tu me tiens à cœur.

On pourrait ajouter :

> Je fais attention à toi,

pour manifester l'attention particulière que l'on porte à l'autre pour lui être agréable.

Comment: *Je prends soin de toi*, c'est *to take care* pas *to care*. *Je fais attention à toi*, ça me parait douteux, quand emploierais-tu cette expression ?

Comment: _Tu me tiens à cœur_ me semble tout aussi étrange.

Comment: J'ai supprimé *je prends soin de toi* - Lorsque la personne est dans un groupe et que mon attention bienveillante ou affectueuse est occupée par elle et que je suis prêt à répondre à ses demandes.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Je l'ai trouvé dans 'linguee' et l'ai déjà entendu, sous la formule 'il te tient à cœur' (pour parler à une personne de sa passion). Mais il est vrai que c'est plutôt employé pour un objet que pour une personne.

Comment: « Je me soucie de toi » me semble être, de loin, la proposition qui répond le mieux à la demande. Cependant il me semble en effet que l’on utilisera plus volontiers « Ça me tient à cœur » que « Tu me tiens à cœur ».